# Were there witch-hunts or witch-trials in China or Japan?

Tags: crime, law-enforcement, witchcraft

Witch trials in medieval and early modern Europe / America are well documented, well known. I am curious if similar existed outside of Christian countries, especially in China and Japan. Both China and Japan have rich mythology about supernatural beings, who often discuss themselves as human and commit smaller or bigger harm to people. One would assume that similar fear among the common folks from these beings existed, and also neither the Chinese nor Japanese were shy if someone had to be tortured to death. So in principle, one would expect that incidents similar to witch trials might have occurred there, too.
I am looking for incidents that:

- formal trial or some other ways formalized (supervised by some laws, authorities), not just lynching or spontaneous violence of a mob;
- not a one-time occasion, but at some extend typical to the region;
- has a mythical or religious motivation (at least officially), and the victim  is accused to be a supernatural being or possessing supernatural powers, but it doesn't need to be a witch;
- it doesn't need to be gender-specific (ie not only women).

As per request about prior research:

- "Asian_witchcraft" of Wikipedia (same as linked in the comment) mentions that folklore indeed has witches both in China and in Japan. No info about law-enforcement or trials or other "non-which-like" candidates.
- "Which hunt" of Wikipedia almost exclusively focuses on European / American cases, without a word about China or Japan. Briefly mentions some very recent (post2000) cases around the world. This lack of information is kind of strange, considering that the second sentence of the article is "The belief in magic and divination, and attempts to use magic to influence personal well-being (to increase life, win love, etc.) are human cultural universals." and even explicitly states: "Reports on indigenous practices in the Americas, Asia and Africa collected during the early modern age of exploration have been taken to suggest that not just the belief in witchcraft but also the periodic outbreak of witch-hunts are a human cultural universal" with a reference to "Behringer, Wolfgang (2004). Witches and Witch-Hunts: A global history."
- "List of people executed for witchcraft" of Wikipedia (strangely ambitious title, to be frank) almost exclusively European / colonial. The only possible candidate on the list is Zhang Liang (Tang dynasty), who was technically trialed for witchcraft. Based on related wiki article Zhang Liang was a general/chancellor to the imperial throne and his trial is primarily politically motivated. While the wiki article mentioned that witchcraft was a major taboo in ancient China, it doesn't mention any similar other cases.
- Google search brought up some online articles about which crafts accusations in present China, mostly from gender/patriarchy angle  (eg. https://theconversation.com/why-are-women-accused-of-witchcraft-study-in-rural-china-gives-clue-89730; https://www.scmp.com/news/china/society/article/2128393/witches-are-banding-together-after-rural-chinese-communities).

In summary, I haven't found any information about regular, formal, or semi-formal prosecution of witches in this region, though similar characters of folklore exist.

Comment: found on wp: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhang_Liang_(Tang_dynasty) (note that in this case, two people were killed, and black magic may not have been the only reason for the persecution)

Comment: Not sure if this counts as "trials", but it seems to have involved lots of official investigations: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chinese_Sorcery_Scare_of_1768

Comment: Great question. Would be good to know about Muslim countries too, though obviously a big subject which needs its own question. I assume many African societies had witch trials, since people are still sometimes killed for being witches among those communities.

Comment: @Jan I do not think that the Zhang Liang case would be much representative as it is about a single case, and the accused was a powerful political leader. The Sorcery Scare of 1768 seems to be something much closer I was interested in: trial or not, local authorities making official investigation in a series of cases. It is strangely specific: this seems like a one-time case, on the other hand, some kind of legal prohibition of sorcery seems to existed if authorities actually followed through.

Comment: Once you believe in magic it is pretty predictable that people who use magic to harm others would be persecuted. Ancient Chinese were pretty strong believers in magic so I suspect such investigations were common. I am actually not familiar with the topic at all, so this is just some stuff I found after a quick google search.

Comment: @Jan That is what I would expect, too, yet I have not found anything on it, hence the question.

Comment: Ronald Hutton’s *The Witch* has a lot about witchcraft beliefs and witch trials that you might find useful.  Not Japan or China specifically, though.

Comment: @Jan, as described in Wikipedia, the Sorcery Scare sounds like a classic witch-hunt.

Comment: Western Europe is far closer, both geographically and culturally, to Eastern Europe than to China or Japan; yet, witch hunts were not *particularly* popular in the equally-Christian East either.

Comment: @Lucian Believes in witches is not exclusive to Christianity or Europe, neither violence against the ones who are believed to be. Actually it is still around. What do you consider Eastern Europe? Balkan was under occupation at that time by the Turks. Hungary had about 1000 witch trials (https://hu.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boszork%C3%A1ny%C3%BCld%C3%B6z%C3%A9s), which is less than in Western Europe, yet still significant number. The low number is often attributed to early legislation by Konyves Kalman (Coloman the Bookish). I have no idea about Poland or Russia.

Comment: @Greg: The only witch hunts I am aware of are heavily influenced by Western Europe, of which Hungary and the Western Slavs form an integral part, since they belong to Western confessions of faith, such as Catholicism or Protestantism. America, famous for its Salem witch trials, was an extension of Western Europe. The modern African witch hunts are, to my knowledge, an (unintended) extension of the evangelistic efforts of American Protestant missionary activity.

Comment: @Lucian Witchraft is punishable with death in Saud Arabia, by law, even nowadays. I am sure those pesky Christian evangelists did it.

Comment: @Greg: I was not aware of that, but I am not surprised, inasmuch as similar things are described in the Hebrew scriptures, and Islam's similarity with Judaism is well-known. At any rate, with Judaism's abandonment of capital punishment in the Early Middle Ages, and witch trials never really amounting to a fad in Eastern Christianity, it's unclear why Far East Asians, of all people, would be (more) attracted to the idea.

Comment: @Lucian Indeed, Eastern Christians preferred to hunt vampires. Oh, those enlightened people, how very different...

Comment: @Greg: True, but the vampires in question were already deceased (one can't exactly kill a corpse that's already dead), and the question itself inquires specifically about witches.

Comment: @Lucian Read the question:"accused to be a supernatural being or possessing supernatural powers, but it doesn't need to be a witch". The point of the question is not to nitpick the definition of witches between cultures, but how legal systems and authorities in general dealt with the fear of supernatural power. Since in many cultures sorcery, magic etc were explicitly forbidden by law, it is a valid question, and it is irrelevant if Slavs preferred to hunt pale, dead gents or elder ladies when some bad luck happened.

Comment: @Greg: According to that logic, the mass hunting of wolves suspected to be werewolves should also be included.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer

Comment: Have you gone through this book: **Telling Stories: Witchcraft And Scapegoating in Chinese History By B. J. ter Haar** ? It's available in Google books.

Comment: thanks, checking it out

Answer (score 3):

"Witchcraft" had very different connotations in Europe than in China or Japan.

In (medieval) Europe, being a witch was connected to [worshipping Satan](https://theconversation.com/the-invention-of-satanic-witchcraft-by-medieval-authorities-was-initially-met-with-skepticism-140809). As such, it was a religious "sin," not merely a secular crime. That's why it was so widely and severely prosecuted.

Asian cultures don't have a concept of "Satan," so there was no conflation of "witches" with "devil worshippers." But "witchcraft" did have its usual connotation of "supernatural powers," so even "superhuman" ability could qualify as witchcraft. Even so, this seemed to be considered an isolated phenomenon (e.g. the Chinese king was jealous of the ability of his general). That explains the absence of "witch hunts" as opposed to one-off "witch trials."

Comment: That seems...hard to believe. 1) There are evil (or at least mischievous) deities/demons in any culture, including Chinese, hence they might have (real or imaginary) followers 2)Even if "witchcraft" is not treated inherently evil, believing that someone has supernatural ability to destroy crops and bring sickness could carry a risk of bringing such person to a trial.

Comment: @Yasskier: I didn't say that there weren't witch "trials" in China (there were). I said, that there were no witch "hunts" in China, of the kind sanctioned by the "church," in Europe.

Comment: @Yasskier The combined concept of satan, witch hunts, and the church are bizarre and foreign in other cultures. Witches existed in China, but were more likely trialled and hanged because they failed to demonstrate anything useful in their snake oil that they sold to the local governor.

Comment: I think your statements would be better if backed up with references. Also, my questions are not about specifical witches, but any person with supernatural powers or supernatural creatures discussed as human. As already linked already demonstrated, fear from supernatural exist in that region, too (just as anywhere else).

Comment: @TomAu The question focuses on trials (as a movement of authorities, religious or other, based on formal legal actions), not on the hunting element (whatever it means). Also, the majority of European which hunts were not "sanctioned by the church", but were done by local authorities.

Comment: In Europe, even when witch trials "were done by local authorities," the church usually provided the impetus. This was not the case in Asia. Which is why there were fewer trials in China and Japan (absent the witch hunting dynamic). "Fear of the supernatural" In Asia was far less than "fear of the devil" in Europe.